# Position three lists horizontal (side by side) in HTML5

Tags: html

I have 3 lists I want to position side by side in html5. What is the best way to do this. I have tried using float and text align in css it just wont work for me. I have been looking at the W3schools tutorials and have looked on here but can't find anything related to lists. I can post the code if needed.

http://pastebin.com/gC6KGaFL Here is the code for the webpage its an assignment for college.

Here is the css http://pastebin.com/xrm8QqeS

Comment: Please post your code *in your question*.

Comment: haha sorry lads brain is mush today, I have tried using float and text align but i can't get one of the lists to center between the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to put your list in div and **position** them (divs) **inline-block**.
Here is the JS fiddle, If I am right.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/dhustlerz/cpp6n4sa/

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked great except for the middle list is not level with the other two any idea how i can level them off.

Comment: It might be just CSS issue. Get me jsfiddle of your code, will figure that out.